# Trying to obtain the resolution of Android device screen

Tags: python, android, screen-resolution, pydroid

I am trying to find the resolution of an Android device. I have already tried using the win32api as well as ctypes but both are not working on my Android device. I am using PyDroid to code my application.

Comment: `I am now trying to get the resolution of an android.` What do you mean? Are you trying to obtain the screen resolution? Default picture resolution? `Of an Android` is kind vauge.

Comment: If you want help, please add some code and expand on your question. We can't really help you with your problem if we don't know what it really is.

Comment: @the_coderCO Yes I am trying to get the screen resolution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PyDroid and its libraries, but after browsing google, I found a [site](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/how+to+get+screen+width+and+height+in+python) that had some promise, because of your mention of `win32api`.

```py
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

print("Width =", GetSystemMetrics(0))
print("Height =", GetSystemMetrics(1))
```

Comment: I think the last one could work but i have an error : screeninfo.common.ScreenInfoError : No enumerators available